# GitLab push not loading local repo

Tags: git

Hi I am new to Github/GitLab. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/git/git_pull_from_remote.asp?remote=gitlab)

I tried to push local repo to remote repo on GitLab. The command ran as expected but when I checked remote repo it did not have any files from local repo uploaded. I noticed  on GitLab ERROR sayin I need to create ssh key first before being able to push to remote. I created rsa key successfully and reran push command which said repo is up to date. But still remote repo is empty. I edited README on remote and committed.
when I run git status this is what I get.

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git
add" to track)

Comment: First add the files you want to the staging area. `git add .` will do.

Comment: A diagram like [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--M_fHUEqA--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://thepracticaldev.s3.amazonaws.com/i/128hsgntnsu9bww0y8sz.png) should help you understand.

Comment: sorry i saw this later after i solved problem.

Answer (score -1):

First I removed the origin then added it back
then `git branch -M main` ,then `git push -uf origin main`
I found this in **Gitlab**